# Почему вторым аргументом add_action вызывается массив, а не функция?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Сейчас разбираю стандартную тему WooCommerce: StoreFront
и наткнулся на такую строчку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В официальной документации WordPress указано, что вторым аргументом 
может быть вызвана функция, но что это ?

Comment: Это метод `setup` в классе `StoreProduct`.

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо за помощь !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему нет? Если посмотреть документацию языка - то можно увидеть, что это полностью нормальный [`callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). Первым элементом массива передаётся объект класса либо имя класса (для статического метода), вторым - имя вызываемого метода.

Comment: Распишите про тип callable и приведите пару примеров :)

Comment: @WPPunk, зачем?

Comment: Чтобы для других пользователей был понятен ответ) То как-то ответ про то, что это нормально не лучшей